# php/mysql query to generate imagemagick image - bad practice?

Tags: php, mysql, imagemagick, imagick

My situation is a relatively simple one: I'd like to generate an image (from an existing original one) whose cropping data is retrieved from a mysql database (it will create the image on the fly; I may save it to the server later, depending on number of image sizes generated), and I'd like the mysql query and imagick (imagemagick) to be in the same php script.

My question is this: is this a bad practice? I'm not so 'pro' in server loads (etc.), and was wondering if a mysql query and imagemagick image generation in the same script would be too slow or load-intensive.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: exactly how often will this have to be done? for every request by every user? say good bye to your server. one a day? once a week? no big deal.

Comment: _"...for every request by every user? say good bye to your server."_

Every request. That bad? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: let's say you've got 100 concurrent users. they all hit the server at the same time, which starts this image processing. an "average" .jpg at 3000x2000 pixels requires 18 meg of ram to hold the raw bitmap, meaning you need 1.8 **GIGABYTES** to hold **JUST** the raw original image. plus extra ram for the processed copy, the os, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image processing is CPU and RAM intensive. You can certainly use image processing in the way you mention, but if your traffic grows fast you'll need to be able to add web/PHP servers easily to let your system scale up.

To make this work well you should open your MySQL connection, perform the query, then close the connection, then do the image processing. That way your MySQL connection pool won't be filled up with connections that sit idle while their processes crunch images.

**Edit** Keeping a cache of already-generated images is an excellent idea. If I were you I'd structure that as a formal cache. When the cache becomes full, it's wise to drop the least-recently *referenced* elements of the cache, not the least recently *generated* ones. That way your frequently used images won't need to be regenerated.

The process of cropping an image is not absurdly expensive in CPU; to do that ImageMagick must decompress the image, crop it, and then recompress it. Most of your computational cost will come up in the decompress/recompress operations (cropping is very cheap). The RAM cost will be proportional to the size of the image. ImageMagick can be compiled from source to exploit a multi-core CPU. You will need to experiment with this to make sure it works.

I made my point about adding servers because it's easier if you design your system to do that upfront.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I do already make a habit of closing connections after ever query (but it's great that you point that out), buuuut... I think I'd rather opt for more HD space (generating the image only if it doesn't exist on the HD, then writing it out there) than 'extra servers'.

I had suspected that it would be load-intensive, but how _much_... hm, thanks.

Comment: Thanks again!

Yes, I can see the logic of setting up 'load-balancing' servers that take care of CPU-intensive stuff like image generation... and why not distribute the HD space across them as well (have them accessible as a unique directory).